# ¿Cuál usa más memoria/procesador en PHP? ¿if o switch?

Tags: php

Un sitio web optimizado no es solamente de menos etiquetas, estilos o plugins, también creo necesario que sea optimizado los recursos en el lado servidor, para un mejor rendimiento.

Entonces el uso de un `if` puede ayudar para ejecutar varios datos que pueden ser ejecutados en uno solo o mediante un `elseif` ejecutar otro script diferente.

```
if($var === 'a' || $var === 'b' || $var === 'c'){
    //Ejecutar
}elseif($var1 === 'd'){
    //Ejecutar
} else {
    //Default
}
```

Y en el uso de un `switch` se ejecuta de una manera muy elegante aunque tiene sus contras, por ejemplo tener que agregar un nuevo `switch` cuando la variable es distinta, por ejemplo:

```
switch ($var) {
    case 'a':
        # code...
        break;
    case 'b':
        # code...
        break;
    case 'c':
        # code...
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
switch ($var1) {
    case 'd':
        # code...
        break;
}
```

Ambos uso se ve sencillo, pero cual ocupa más recurso, más que una opinión es un tema importante que creo que se debe tener en cuenta para aplicaciones con mucho más rendimiento.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Prólogo

Cada caso de uso podría arrojar resultados diferentes por motivos diferentes, por lo que la afirmación razonada en esta respuesta sólo es válida en particular a este caso de uso, aunque podría definirse como un caso bastante general.

Así que podemos afirmar que, en este caso en particular, el rendimiento de un `switch`/`case` es superior al de bloques `if`/`else` en cuanto a velocidad de ejecución, pero que en cuanto a uso de memoria es peor un `switch`/`case` respecto al `if`/`else` .

Además, en todos los casos los bloques `switch`/`case` fallarían al comparar el valor inicial de `$letra` en las pruebas, que es `0`, al compararlo con la letra `a`, ya que `0 == 'a'` da como resultado `true` (el tipo de comparación que usa `switch`/`case`), mientras que `0 === 'a'` da como resultado `false` (tipo de comparación usada en los `if`):

```
$ php7.2 -r 'var_dump(0 == "a");'
bool(true)
$ php7.2 -r 'var_dump(0 === "a");'
bool(false)
```

### Entorno de pruebas

Para las pruebas he creado dos archivos:

**if.php**

```
<?php
$letras = 'abcdefghijk';
for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++) {
  $letra = 0;
  $caso1 = 0;
  $caso2 = 0;
  $start = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++, $letra = $letras[$i % strlen($letras)]) {
    if ($letra === 'a' || $letra === 'b' || $letra === 'c') {
      $caso1++;
    } else if ($letra === 'd') {
      $caso2++;
    }
  }
  printf(
    '[if-else %d] Time: %.3f s (c1: %d, c2: %d)%s',
    $c,
    microtime(true) - $start,
    $caso1,
    $caso2,
    PHP_EOL
  );
}
```

**switch.php**

```
<?php
$letras = 'abcdefghijk';
for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++) {
  $letra = 0;
  $caso1 = 0;
  $caso2 = 0;
  $start = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++, $letra = $letras[$i % strlen($letras)]) {
    switch($letra) {
      case 'a':
      case 'b':
      case 'c':
        $caso1++;
        break;
      case 'd':
        $caso2++;
    }
  }
  printf(
    '[switch %d] Time: %.3f s (c1: %d, c2: %d)%s',
    $c,
    microtime(true) - $start,
    $caso1,
    $caso2,
    PHP_EOL
  );
}
```

### Tiempo de ejecución

Y he ejecutado consecutivamente y en el mismo entorno de PHP ambos scripts:

```
$ php7.2 -r "require 'if.php'; require 'switch.php';"
[if-else 0] Time: 6.232 s (c1: 27272727, c2: 9090909)
[if-else 1] Time: 6.228 s (c1: 27272727, c2: 9090909)
[if-else 2] Time: 6.225 s (c1: 27272727, c2: 9090909)
[switch 0] Time: 3.654 s (c1: 27272728, c2: 9090909)
[switch 1] Time: 3.653 s (c1: 27272728, c2: 9090909)
[switch 2] Time: 3.657 s (c1: 27272728, c2: 9090909)
```

### Uso de memoria

Para calcular el impacto en memoria he usado:

```
$ php -r "require 'if.php'; echo memory_get_peak_usage(), PHP_EOL;"
[if-else 0] Time: 6.245 s (c1: 27272727, c2: 9090909)
[if-else 1] Time: 6.224 s (c1: 27272727, c2: 9090909)
[if-else 2] Time: 6.218 s (c1: 27272727, c2: 9090909)
432832
$ php -r "require 'switch.php'; echo memory_get_peak_usage(), PHP_EOL;"
[switch 0] Time: 4.032 s (c1: 27272728, c2: 9090909)
[switch 1] Time: 4.038 s (c1: 27272728, c2: 9090909)
[switch 2] Time: 4.027 s (c1: 27272728, c2: 9090909)
433136
```

### Caso base:

Para poder calcular el incremento de tiempo y memoria del `case` respecto del `if` hay que tomar un caso base en el que se tenga en cuenta el tiempo todo aquello que no está relacionado con las pruebas:

**base.php**

```
<?php
$letras = 'aaaa';
for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++) {
  $letra = 0;
  $caso1 = 0;
  $caso2 = 0;
  $start = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++, $letra = $letras[$i % strlen($letras)]) {
  }
  printf(
    '[if-else %d] Time: %.3f s (c1: %d, c2: %d)%s',
    $c,
    microtime(true) - $start,
    $caso1,
    $caso2,
    PHP_EOL
  );
}
```

Los resultados:

```
$ php -r "require 'base.php'; echo memory_get_peak_usage(), PHP_EOL;"
[if-else 0] Time: 2.545 s (c1: 0, c2: 0)
[if-else 1] Time: 2.545 s (c1: 0, c2: 0)
[if-else 2] Time: 2.544 s (c1: 0, c2: 0)
432256
```

### Resultados:

- Mejor tiempo de ejecución: `switch`. `3,687` > `1,109` (un `232%` más).
- Mejor uso de memoria: `if`. `576` < `880` (un `53%` más).

### Otros casos de uso

Como dije en el prólogo a esta respuesta, depende del caso los resultados pueden aumentar o disminuir.

Un ejemplo muy rápido que muestra cómo puede afectar un simple cambio es modificando esta línea en ambos scripts:

```
$letras = 'abcd';
```

Arrojando ahora unos resultados más ajustados entre ambos:

```
$ php7.2 -r "require 'if.php'; require 'switch.php';"
[if-else 0] Time: 5.478 s (c1: 74999999, c2: 25000000)
[if-else 1] Time: 5.485 s (c1: 74999999, c2: 25000000)
[if-else 2] Time: 5.483 s (c1: 74999999, c2: 25000000)
[switch 0] Time: 4.140 s (c1: 75000000, c2: 25000000)
[switch 1] Time: 4.141 s (c1: 75000000, c2: 25000000)
[switch 2] Time: 4.140 s (c1: 75000000, c2: 25000000)
```

- Mejor tiempo de ejecución: `switch`. `2,938` > `1,595` (un `84%` más).

Cambiar la cadena al primer caso del `or` del `if`:

```
$letras = 'aaaa';
```

Acercaría aún más los resultados:

```
$ php7.2 -r "require 'if.php'; require 'switch.php';"
[if-else 0] Time: 4.259 s (c1: 99999999, c2: 0)
[if-else 1] Time: 4.254 s (c1: 99999999, c2: 0)
[if-else 2] Time: 4.275 s (c1: 99999999, c2: 0)
[switch 0] Time: 3.829 s (c1: 100000000, c2: 0)
[switch 1] Time: 3.834 s (c1: 100000000, c2: 0)
[switch 2] Time: 3.832 s (c1: 100000000, c2: 0)
```

- Mejor tiempo de ejecución: `switch`. `1,714` > `1,287` (un `33%` más).

Comment: He creado un caso base, porque habría que eliminar de la comparación los tiempos de ejecución de los propios bucles, incremento de la variable contador, cálculo de la letra que toca, etc y el uso de memoria del código base y sus variables. Si todos los casos están cubiertos (`$letras` vale `abcd`) la diferencia de ejecución es del `84%` y de uso de memoria del `53%`.

Comment: Aún así no suelo tener problemas de cuellos de botella de CPU en ningún servidor PHP de los que administro, sin embargo sí que debo estar ajustando los procesos simultáneos de apache2 (si uso `mod_php`) o los procesos `php-fpm` para que no se agote la memoria y se use el archivo de intercambio.

Comment: No pasa nada. No ha sido molestia, todo lo contrario, ha sido un incentivo para mejorar la respuesta agregando el caso base :)

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia excelente aporte, muy útil todas las consideraciones que haz proporcionado, gracias por compartirlo.

Answer (score 1):

En el caso que planteas, estas mezclando dos logicas distintas y por tanto suponiendo un "contra" que no es como tal.

**EL IF:**

Date cuenta que la estructura de `if` que propones, ejecutaria la primera parte si se da el caso de alguno de los OR.

si no se cumple, analizas otra variable distinta y si se cumple ejecutas otro codigo distinto,

y si no se cumple nada, hace el `else`.

en resumen:

logica 1: solo si se cumple `$var === 'a' || $var === 'b' || $var === 'c'`

logica 2: solo si se cumple que `$var1 === 'd'`

logica 3: solo si NO se cumplen las anteriores.

**EL SWITCH:**

Por contra, el `switch` que propones ejecuta distinto codigo para cada una de las opciones (no es lo mismo). Y luego haces otro switch completamente distinto para comprobar otra variable. Puede darse el siguiente caso:

$var=='a'.   $var1 == 'd'

El `if` Solo mostraria el codigo que hay en la primera condicion.

los `switch` mostrarian el codigo de la primera condicion `y` de la segunda condicion.

**si no son las mismas logicas, no se puede comparar dichos rendimientos.**

Comment: Hola @Jakala son buenos puntos de vistas, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El switch es mas rapido, consume menos memoria, ya que un if elseif tiene que comprobar todas las comparaciones y el switch  directamente accede a la que es y las demas no las comprueba aqui tienes una expliación mas tecnica y detalla pero basicamente es eso.

https://elbauldelprogramador.com/por-que-un-switch-es-mas-rapido-que-su-homologo-if-then-else/

Comment: el problema aqui es que esta comparando dos logicas distintas, y por tanto no es correcto decir que una es mas rapida que otra. la logica del if se ejecuta en ciertos casos, los dos switch se ejecutan siempre que se cumpla la condicion

Comment: yo entiendo que la respuesta es para una misma logica, esta claro que si son logicas distintas no tiene sentido

Comment: Ese enlace que has proporcionado no puede aplicarse ni remotamente al caso de PHP. El primer motivo de ello es que el compilador ha optimizado los saltos por ser numéricos contiguos, por lo que almacena consecutivamente los punteros a los que debe saltar en `.L7:` y luego salta al índice restándole 100 en `subl $100, %eax`. En segundo caso es que en C los `switch` sólo pueden ser numéricos, en PHP podrían ser cualquier cosa, incluso el resultado de evaluar algo (operadores para realizar cálculos, llamadas a funciones, etc). Si apoyas tu respuesta con algo sólido te daré mi voto.